# Is it possible to post process in Quarkus CDI like it is possible in Spring DI?

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection, quarkus

I know that Quarkus does dependency injection at build-time. The problem is the following:
Let's say I have a bean which has some of its fields annotated with certain annotation. I want to do something with this bean before it gets injected in other beans. Is there a workaround for this or not? Where should I start?

In Spring (Boot) I would probably use BeanPostProcessor, but I coudln't find anything like this in Quarkus

Comment: It would be good if you added more details about what exactly you want to do with that bean. It may turn out that it's possible to do that during build, in which case Quarkus has a pretty extensive extension API.

Comment: @Ladicek The example is in the post itself. I want to modify annotated field of a bean.

Comment: OK so you want the container to create a bean, give you a chance to set some fields or otherwise modify the instance, and only then allow the container to inject that instance to other beans? I don't think CDI has anything for this, but it should be possible to use a producer method to achieve something similar (likely somewhat more complex, as you have to fully construct the instance manually in a producer).